# Properly visualize data in a bar chart

Tags: excel, charts, excel-charts

My data looks like this

| Group | Status | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| G1 | A | 2 |
| G1 | B | 5 |
| G1 | C | 1 |
| G2 | B | 3 |
| G2 | C | 4 |

How can I chart this properly in excel?

Currently this is what my chart looks like
[image: My Chart]

How can I make the legend on the right correspond to Status while having the Y axis corresponding to the Group?

Comment: How would you picture the Count then? Would a [bubble chart](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/present-your-data-in-a-bubble-chart-424d7bda-93e8-4983-9b51-c766f3e330d9) be good for you?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
Sub SubReproduceExample()
    
    Dim ObjChart As Object
    Dim ObjSeries As Object
    
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    
    Range("A1").FormulaR1C1 = "Group"
    Range("A2").FormulaR1C1 = "G1"
    Range("A3").FormulaR1C1 = "G1"
    Range("A4").FormulaR1C1 = "G1"
    Range("A5").FormulaR1C1 = "G2"
    Range("A6").FormulaR1C1 = "G2"
    Range("B1").FormulaR1C1 = "Status"
    Range("B2").FormulaR1C1 = "A"
    Range("B3").FormulaR1C1 = "B"
    Range("B4").FormulaR1C1 = "C"
    Range("B5").FormulaR1C1 = "B"
    Range("B6").FormulaR1C1 = "C"
    Range("C1").FormulaR1C1 = "Count"
    Range("C2").FormulaR1C1 = "2"
    Range("C3").FormulaR1C1 = "5"
    Range("C4").FormulaR1C1 = "1"
    Range("C5").FormulaR1C1 = "3"
    Range("C6").FormulaR1C1 = "4"
    Range("D1").FormulaR1C1 = "Label"
    Range("D2:D6").FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-3]&"" ""&RC[-2]"
    Range("E1").FormulaR1C1 = "Y"
    Range("E2:E6").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-4]<>R[-1]C[-4],IFERROR(R[-1]C+1,1),R[-1]C)"
    Range("F1").FormulaR1C1 = "X"
    Range("F2:F6").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(COUNTIF(R1C2:R[-1]C[-4],RC[-4])=0,IFERROR(MAX(R1C6:R[-1]C)+1,1),INDEX(R1C6:R[-1]C,MATCH(RC[-4],R1C2:R[-1]C[-4],0)))"
    
    Set ObjChart = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(-1, xlBubble) '269
    With ObjChart.Chart
        .SetSourceData Source:=Range("$C$1:$F$6")
        For Each ObjSeries In .SeriesCollection
            ObjSeries.Delete
        Next
        .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        With .SeriesCollection(1)
            .Name = Range("$C$1")
            .XValues = Range("$F$2:$F$6")
            .Values = Range("$E$2:$E$6")
            .BubbleSizes = Range("$C$2:$C$6")
        End With
        .ApplyDataLabels
        With .SeriesCollection(1)
            .DataLabels.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.InsertChartField msoChartFieldRange, "=" & Split(Range("$D$2:$D$6").Address(, , , True), "]")(1), 0 '"=Foglio1!$D$2:$D$6", 0
            .DataLabels.ShowRange = True
            .DataLabels.ShowBubbleSize = True
            .DataLabels.ShowValue = False
            .DataLabels.Separator = "" & Chr(13) & ""
        End With
        .SetElement (msoElementPrimaryCategoryAxisNone)
        .SetElement (msoElementPrimaryValueAxisNone)
    End With
    
End Sub
```

It will re-create the example you've provided in a new sheet with a possible bubble chart. Extra formulas in the range D1:F6 grants the coordinates for the bubbles (each group has a row and each status has a column) and a label to be added to each bubble to identify their group and status.

The result should looks like this:
[image]